# getDefault() of SSLContext from where this object is created

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

Acutally I want to know:

When we call `SSLContext.getDefault()` to get `SSLContext` instanse, from where this (returned object) SSLContext is created.

is It either created from:

- local machine specific
- java internal specific
- as per web server configuration did in `server.xml`  based (in case used in web based application)

or some thing else.

Comment: What's the difference between the first two?

Comment: First one is trying to indicate that SSL info is loaded from machine while second one is from JDK embeded SSL info, I am very new to all this, may be my assumption is wrong.